# Getting data from get in controller PHP

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, get

I'm trying to get some data via $.GET in jQuery. I have a link and after clicking this I want to receive data in the controller. I've made this but it doesn't work, the $_GET array is empty:

html.twig:

```
<a href="{{path('current')}}" id="get">Some name</a>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click','#get', function(){
                $.get({{path('current', {'id' : 'a1'})}}, function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            });

        });

        </script>
```

Controller:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

The route name is O.K. Maybe some other ideas how to get data in controller by clicking the link? I don't want to use $.ajax

Comment: Is this a question about symphony? (I'm figuring that from the name `html.twig`) If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Did you use the firebug to debug ? please check the request parameters, response result and request url in firebug console. Figure out what happened via firebug.

Comment: If rendered by twig, this part:`$.get({{path('current', {'id' : 'a1'})}},` will produce invalid javascript (missing quotes).

Comment: Yes, I've checked there. I get the response but the $_GET array is empty

Comment: Yoshi, I've added quotes, thanks, but I still get nothing in $_GET.

Comment: Don't use `$_GET` inside a symfony controller, use `xxxAction(Request $request) { $val = $request->query->get('key'); ...`

Comment: I know, but what is the key in this case? I tried 'get' like ID as the key, but still nothing

Comment: The key depends on how the route is configured. It will only be a part of the query (`$request->query)` if it's **not** part of the route definition. E.g. `/some-dir/{notId}`. But if it is part of the route (`/some-dir/{id}`), then you'll have to inject it into the method. E.g. `xxxAction($id)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any AJAX if you just want your server to recieve request. You can use your link with the same parameters:

```
<a href="{{path('current', {'id' : 'a1'})}}" id="get">Some name</a>
```

This link will send GET request to your server and you will be able to get access to it. The only distinction is that you will be redirected to a new page rendered by your controller. But as you say: you don't need AJAX.

Also you need to understand that retrieve parameters with `$_GET` is a bad practice. You must use `$request->get('id')` if you want to handle both `GET` and `POST` request with the same parameters. And `$request->query->get('id')` if you only want access to GET-request parameters.

But in your case I think that you have `id` parameter in your route definition and then you can get access to it by defining action as:

```
public function currentAction(Request $request, $id) {
    // $id - is your parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your twig clean of javascript and use data property to retrieve the path:

```
<a href="#_" data-posturl="{{path('current', {'id' : 'a1'})}}" id="get">Some name</a>
```

in your js file :

```
$(document).on('click','#get', function(){
                $.post($(this).data('posturl')).done(function (data) {
        }).error(function (data) {
            $('body').prepend(data.responseText);
        });});
```

and in your action your should be able to get your id as parameter to your action if it was defined in the route. Otherwise it would be available in the request.